# Remote vs local exploits

Tags: exploit

Would a remote exploit such as ETERNALBLUE work on any target computer over the internet if you targeted the right ip or does it have to be on the same network and what would be examples of a local exploit and a remote (Like is the remote only over a network close to you in your range, while with local you have to have some type of access with the computer?)

Answer (score 2):

Remote exploits are exploits that you can run on an external machine. Local exploits are exploits that you can run only with access to the machine (f.e. Privilege Escalations).

A remote exploit may be on a host inside an intranet, accessible only by few people, but also inside the internet, accessible by everyone.

Comment: Can you run a remote exploit cross world and or send it cross world without them downloading a file? like how would that work, could you link any articles, because I am currently trying to understand the limits on a remote exploit.

Comment: Like um, does the remote attack have to be over the same network?

Comment: The network doesn't matter in this term. You in some cases you can and in some cases you can't. You can have a remote exploit in a service on a host in an intranet. Then you need access to the intranet. But as long as you can connect to the hosts network segment, you can use a remote exploit.

Comment: Simply put, for a remote exploit the attacking machine must be able to get some network package(s) to the target machine. In most cases this is easier from inside the LAN, but the term "remote" simply doesn't state if it's from the LAN or from outside.

Comment: So lets say a simple remote SMB like Eternal, Would it be possible to just do it fully over the Intranet or how would you get an exploit that would work over the intranet that would not need you connected to the host's network in the first place, such as a fully cross world exploit. without sending a PDF/EXE and such.

Comment: Ok, seems like I can't communicate my point. The point is that the network doesn't matter in this context. You can configure your intranet so you can't contact any other host, or you can configure it that you can contact every host. In first case you can't use your SMB remote exploit. In second case you can, because you can contact other hosts.

Comment: Most Remote exploits are working through the programs they are found for as its like the computer would read over it but encounter the code as it would interpenetrate the code and fall into the trap of the user who sent it.